# In Mongo, how to change field value after certain amount of time has passed

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Versions of this question have been asked for many databases but I did not see a version of this question on stackoverflow for MongoDB. We have a **users** collection in our database, and we are trying to create trial accounts for our website. We have the following user schema:

```
{
  name: 'Joe Smith',
  email: 'joesmith@gmail.com',
  userTier: { value: 0, label: 'none' }
}
```

When a user signs up, their `userTier` starts at `{ value: 0, label: 'none' }`, when they verify their email address, `userTier` goes to `{ value: 1, label: 'verified' }` via a route in our Node API:

```
router.get('/verify-email/:userId/:token', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { userId, token } = req.params;
        const emailToken = await EmailVerificationToken.findOne({ token: token });
        if (!emailToken) { // bad token, do not verify
            return res.redirect(`${frontEndUrl}/verify-email-page/no-token`);
        }

        const thisUser = await User.findOne({ _id: userId });
        if (!thisUser) { // no user found, do not verify
            return res.redirect(`${frontEndUrl}/verify-email-page/no-user`);
        }

        if (thisUser.tier.value > 0) { // if already verified
            return res.redirect(`${frontEndUrl}/verify-email-page/already-verified`);
        }

        // otherwise, verify user
        thisUser.tier = { value: 1, label: 'verified' };
        thisUser.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.redirect(`${frontEndUrl}/verify-email-page/cant-save-user`);
            }
            res.redirect(`${frontEndUrl}/verify-email-page/success`);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500, message: error.message });
    }
});
```

...not a perfect route with the different `res.redirect()`s, but it gets the job done. We are now looking for a way to temporarily update the `userTier` to `{ value: 2, label: 'trial' }` for 1-2 weeks, after which the value automatically changes back to `{ value: 1, label: 'verified' }`. We would prefer a mongo-only approach (perhaps we can set an `expiration` field in the user schema that automatically changes the `userTier` value when the expiration time is reached), although it seems unlikely that this is possible... How are 1 week trials typically coded up under the hood when using mongo + node?

Comment: Maybe create a separate collection for the "trial" data (store some basic related info), and 
 create a TTL (Time To Live) index.  When a document gets deleted (automatically because of the TTL), a "trigger" updates the `userTier`. This 'trigger' can be a Change Stream _or_ [Command Monitoring](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/monitoring/command-monitoring/). That said, a CRON job can be used to trigger a process, which can be run every six hours or daily - depending upon your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a MongoDB-only way. I suggest that you set a Node.js cron function that would execute every night/morning and would deactivate the expired trials.

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

const job = schedule.scheduleJob('0 1 * * *', function(){
   // update the users for whom the trial expired 
});
```

MongoDB in the end is powered by a server that may crash or would restart when the machine restarts anyway. As far I know, there is no such functionality as memorising particular actions in the database server itself.

Instead, you can have a middleware to check if the trial expired.

Comment: haven't heard of node-schedule before, this is very interesting thanks.

Comment: With this solution, if the server goes down the whole cron job goes down as well.

Comment: well, I faced a similar preoccupation. One of the solutions I found was to develop a completely separate SubscriptionManager class, implementing a singleton pattern, hence making it unique system-wide.

then we could add a member variable to this class, of preference map of user id to their subscription, and create a middle ware that uses this. This limits database calls and hence reduce latency and load. But I believe this could cause memory issues and you equally have to listen to db events for the related collection to be assured that the app remains at sync, if you need that.